# Relationship between sin and cos when $\sin x = -5/7$ and $x$ is a third-quadrant angle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am stuck on this problem:

$\sin x = -\frac{5}{7}$, where I have to find what $\tan 2x$ is if $x$ is in the third quadrant. The main part I am confused on is how I am getting a negative $\frac{\sqrt {24}}{7}$ rather than a positive $\frac{\sqrt{24}}{7}$ for $\cos x$. The textbook says that the $\cos x$ is the positive version.

Comment: You are correct. If $x$ is in the third quadrant, both $\sin$ and $\cos$ are negative.

Comment: @Landuros But the answer(value of x) would be negative right? I plugged it into the calc and I'm really only confused on how i got the ending result of x to be a negative, when the calc says its positive. When you divide a negative fraction by a negative fraction(dividing sin by cos to get tan) the tan should be positive. However, when i use the double angle identitiy for tan, I get a negative denominator resulting in a negative answer.

Comment: You should get a negative value for $\tan(2x)$ since $\tan x > 1 \implies 1 - \tan^2x < 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that both $\cos x$ and $\tan(2x)$ are negative.

Using the Pythagorean identity $\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\sin^2x + \cos^2x & = 1\\
\cos^2x & = 1 - \sin^2x\\
\cos^2x & = 1 - \left(-\frac{5}{7}\right)^2\\
\cos^2x & = 1 - \frac{25}{49}\\
\cos^2x & = \frac{24}{49}\\
|\cos x| & = \sqrt{\frac{24}{49}}\\
|\cos x| & = \frac{2\sqrt{6}}{7}\\
\cos x & = -\frac{2\sqrt{6}}{7}
\end{align*}
since $\cos x$ is negative in the third-quadrant.

Hence,
$$\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = \frac{-\frac{5}{7}}{-\frac{2\sqrt{6}}{7}} = \frac{5}{2\sqrt{6}} = \frac{5\sqrt{6}}{12}$$
Observe that 
$$5^2 = 25 > 24 = (2\sqrt{6})^2$$
Since both $5$ and $2\sqrt{6}$ are positive, the inequality is preserved when we take square roots, so $5 > 2\sqrt{6}$.  Hence,
$$\tan x = \frac{5}{2\sqrt{6}} > 1$$
Therefore,
$$1 - \tan^2x < 0$$
Since $\tan x > 0$ and $1 - \tan^2x < 0$, 
$$\tan(2x) = \frac{2\tan x}{1 - \tan^2x} < 0$$
I will leave the calculation of the value of $\tan(2x)$ to you.